# New Find Usage pop-up in IntelliJ IDEA places code fragments at the end (not visible)

Tags: intellij-idea

Since some time IDEA has new Find Usages pop-up, which is completely unusable to me because code fragments is not visible:

[image]

Before it looked like this:

[image]

This affects at least version 2021.2.1. I've tried searching settings but couldn't find anything related to visual view of Find Usages pop-up. Is it possible to reconfigure it to be like it was before (code first)?

Comment: Does remove `<component name="ShowUsagesSettings">` tag from `${idea.config.path}/options/usageView.xml` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try 2021.2.2 version - it has improvements for this popup:

*[IDEA-275480](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275480) Show usages popup: a lot of space is occupied by uninteresting data and actual usage text doesn't fit the popup*